# When the pop up menu automatically appears and I press `Ctrl + S`. It pastes `:w`?

Tags: vim

I'm using an [Auto Completion Pop Up](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) script.

When I place the cursor

```
left:(here) 218px !important;
```

or

```
left: (here) 218px !important;
```

the pop up menu automatically appears as usual, then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and it pastes `:w`. I think it is trying to complete `:` for `:w`.

Any suggestions to fix this?

I have this in my vimrc:

```
" Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode
noremap <C-S> :w<CR>
vnoremap <C-S> <C-C>:w<CR>
imap <C-S> <C-O>:w<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `<Esc>` instead of `<C-O>` solved the problem.

```
noremap <C-S> :w!<CR>
vnoremap <C-S> <Esc>:w!<CR>
inoremap <C-S> <Esc>:w!<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Auto Completion script provided there doesn't work for me so I can't give a correct way to actually fix the problem, but as far as I can tell the issue is as follows.

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> command that you use doesn't do anything more than enter `:w` followed by Carriage Return in vim's [Normal Mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#vim-modes-intro). `:w` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the *actual* way of saving a file in vim, your <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is a shortcut to that.

I'm led to believe that that pop up plugin somehow prevents the shortcut to make a quick switch to normal mode, thus inserting `:w` into your actual document.